# The content of the Intent in the BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android

I am learning how to send SMS in android, have seen the code as below:

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
   {
   //---get the SMS message passed in---
   Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
   SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
   String str = “”;
   if (bundle != null)
   {
      //---retrieve the SMS message received---
      Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get(“pdus”);
      msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
      for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
         msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
         str += “SMS from “ + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
         str += “ :”;
         str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
         str += “\n”;
   }
    //---display the new SMS message---
   Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  }
}
```

Now my question is how do I know what are the contents of Intent object that are passed into onReceive function? As below:

```
Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get(“pdus”);
```

How do I know there is a "pdus" key in the bundle object?
I can't find any clue in the API doc, anyone know where is the related information located?

I don't only want to know what the SMS intent pass into onReceive function, but also the other system related Intent, but I can't locate any related information in the API doc. I wonder does the information really exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the bundle contains a Key value pair with key `pdus` using   `bundle.containsKey("pdus")` which returns `true` if there are any `Protocol Data Units` (PDUs which in your case are SMSes).

So, the check for processing the PDUs should be `if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey("pdus"))`

Comment: Actually I am not asking this, I want to know all the possible key in the bundle and what kind of value they keep, but so far, I can't find them in the API doc. I suppose they are documented somewhere, but just can't find it.

Comment: All possible keys can be obtained using [keySet()] (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#keySet()). The kind of value they keep for (any of the) standard `intent filters` is not documented AFAIK.

Comment: How come they don't document those key? Then how do we know what are those key stand for? Even I print out those key by using KeySet() function, but I am still not clear what are they. Pardon, how do you know what "psud" stand for while you dealing with SMS? I posted something in the answer below, can you help me with that?

Comment: `Intent filters` are defined by the application. You'd have to look at the documentation for the paritcular application you're interested in. The developer site actually documents all the non-modifiable parts of the android framework. I think these intent filters can be modified in the firmware (though its not a good idea to do it) by the manufacturers and thats the reason its not documented.

Answer (score 1):

I swiped this code from this page: http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/15/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages/

```
SmsMessage[] messages = Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent);
```

It looks like Android might already have a mechanism to get your messages. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I hope they have the mechanism to get the messages, but unfortunately, the function you posted does not exist in the API framework.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
   //sendSMS(“5556”, “Hello my friends!”);
   Intent i = new
   Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   i.putExtra(“address”, “5556; 5558; 5560”);
   i.putExtra(“sms_body”, “Hello my friends!”);
   i.setType(“vnd.android-dir/mms-sms”);
   startActivity(i);
}
```

How can we check all those possible key when we want to pass into the intent for invoking the SMS application as above? I hope they are documented somewhere.